# Git: remove a duplicate commit

Tags: git, git-branch

I don't know how but I have the following log :

```
* 527795c - (HEAD, origin/master, master)
*   b829011 - Merge branch 'master'
|\  
| * 423e3aa - Some files added
| * b4c60f2 - Initial commit
* a838a27 - Initial commit
```

Commits `a838a27` and `b4c60f2` are the same (all the modifications are exactly the same).

How I can remove commit `a838a27`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those commits are the same, then `b829011 - Merge branch 'master'` isn't useful at all.

Your history could be just `b4c60f2`, `423e3aa` and `527795c`.

One simple solution would be to:

- rename the current `master` branch in `master old`
- create a `master` branch at `423e3aa`
- cherry-pick `527795c`
- delete `master-old`
- force push the new `master` to origin (beware: it will change the history on origin, so make sure to warn any user having cloned that upstream repo bore your changes)

That is:

```
git branch -m master master_old
git checkout -b master 423e3aa
git cherry-pick 527795c
git branch -d master_old
git push --force -u origin master
```

Make sure the history is correct *before* force pushing.

Comment: Awesome, my git history is now beautiful !

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer from VonC (would make a comment, not allowed...) if you have more commits than just `527795c` between this merge and `HEAD` (or if anyone else does) you'll find 
`git rebase`
saves you cherrypicking every single one.

One way this situation could have arisen is: `git checkout --orphan new_branch`

Comment: Could you make an example, please ? :-)